# GreenSock JS smooth parallax on mousewheel

Tags: javascript, parallax, gsap

I've been playing around with greensock js which is a great tool for smooth animations. I'm trying to rebuild a simple script that smooths the body scrolling to scroll DOM elements with different speed ending up with nice "hd" parallax effect. Here is the code

```
$(function(){

var $window = $(window);        //Window object
var $parallax = document.getElementById('parallax');        //parallax object

var scrollTime = 0.3;           //Scroll time
var scrollDistance = 200;       //Distance. Use smaller value for shorter scroll and greater value for longer scroll
var parallaxDistance = 150;

$window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event){

    event.preventDefault(); 

    var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta/120 || -event.originalEvent.detail/3;
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var finalScroll = scrollTop - parseInt(delta*scrollDistance);
    var finalParallax = scrollTop - parseInt(delta*parallaxDistance);

    TweenMax.to($window, scrollTime, {
        scrollTo : { y: finalScroll, autoKill:true },
            ease: Power1.easeOut,   //For more easing functions see http://api.greensock.com/js/com/greensock/easing/package-detail.html
            autoKill: true,
            overwrite: 5                            
        });

    TweenMax.to($parallax , scrollTime, {
        scrollTo : { y: finalParallax, autoKill:true },
            ease: Power1.easeOut,   //For more easing functions see http://api.greensock.com/js/com/greensock/easing/package-detail.html
            autoKill: true,
            overwrite: 5                            
        });


});

});
```

First TweenMax.to() operation works perfect but second is not. 
Please check the original article with demo of smooth scrolling http://blog.bassta.bg/2013/05/smooth-page-scrolling-with-tweenmax/
What I want to achieve is scrolling for example the header text with different speed (scroll value actually).

Any ideas on that? THX in advance!